# How does jvm react to this

Tags: java, jvm

```
interface CanFight {
  void fight();
}

interface CanSwim {
  void swim();
}

interface CanFly {
  void fly();
}

class ActionCharacter {
  public void fight() {
      System.out.println("Inside class fight");
  }
}

class Hero extends ActionCharacter
    implements CanFight, CanSwim, CanFly {
  public void swim() {}
  public void fly() {}
}

      public class MultipleInterface {
  public static void t(CanFight x) { x.fight(); }
  public static void u(CanSwim x) { x.swim(); }
  public static void v(CanFly x) { x.fly(); }
  public static void w(ActionCharacter x) { x.fight(); }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hero h = new Hero();
    t(h); // Treat it as a CanFight
    u(h); // Treat it as a CanSwim
    v(h); // Treat it as a CanFly
    w(h); // Treat it as an ActionCharacter
  }
}
```

How does JVM behave as I am not implementing method from `canFight` interface but it takes it from `ActionCharacter` class? What is the logic behind it? Point is I am not defining method `fight()` that must be done if implementing `canFight()` interface.

Comment: Try it! SO is not a place for questions that you can simply try and see!!

Comment: What you get when you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the much the JVM, but the Java compiler. (If the JVM finds a method missing that should be there, you get a NoSuchMethodException, but the compiler won't let you get to that point unless you trick it).

As for your question, it does not matter which class or superclass or interface a method is declared in, only the name and signature need to match. Thus, `ActionCharacter#fight` and `CanFight#fight` declare the same thing. Java makes no distinction between the two (neither the compiler nor the JVM/bytecode format).

Your `Hero` inherits `fight` from `ActionCharacter`, but since it happens to also match the method defined in `CanFight`, it also doubles as an implementation of that interface.

Could be clearer to either change the method name (if those are supposed to be two different methods) or have `ActionCharacter` also implement `CanFight` (if this is indeed intended to be the same method).

Comment: so is it a lapse or a feature ?

Comment: Depends on your viewpoint. To be sure, it prevents you from defining two semantically different method interfaces with the same name and signature. But you should probably choose better names, then.

Answer (score 2):

If a type implements two interfaces, and each interface define a method that has identical signature, then in effect there is only one method, and they are not distinguishable.

If, say, the two methods have conflicting return types, then it will be a compilation error. This is the general rule of inheritance, method overriding, hiding, and declarations, and applies also to possible conflicts not only between 2 inherited interface methods, but also an interface and a super class method, or even just conflicts due to type erasure of generics.

It's said in [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#228059)

> It is permitted for a single method declaration in a class to
>   implement methods of more than one superinterface.

Answer (score 1):

You are extending `ActionCharacter` which means you want all the operations and attributes of `ActionCharacter` inherited to your `Hero` class.

This include `fight` operation as well. You mark `Hero` as implementing `CanFight` but you inherit the actual implementation from `ActionCharacter`.

Comment: why it doesn't throw error when I am not implmenting Fight though implementing canFIght interface ?

Comment: It is like you (Hero) inherit All your money from your Father (in this case ActionCharacter) so you now have isRich operation inside you even though all the money you have came from your father. Eventhough you didn't earn them you have money so you are rich. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @shazin: the problem with this of course is if ActionCharacter's idea of "rich" is completely unrelated to that interface.

Answer (score 0):

Hero is required to implement `void figth();` but it inherits `void figth();` from ActionCharacter so the requirement is met.

Comment: the problem with this (and I guess the point of the question) is if you intended this two be two semantically different methods. Java (neither compiler nor JVM) cannot keep them apart.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces only declares a method , you cannot define a method in an interface. So what it means is that you give a draft of what you want to implement in an interface.

Now here, your class Hero inherits class ActionCharacter which has a definition of public void fight(). However, this fight() has no connection with fight() of CanFight. so if you define a fight() in Hero, you will override the fight() of ActionCharacter.

Since you also implement the interface CanFight, jvm will allow this as you have declared the method in CanFight, but it will be treated as override of fight() of ActionCharacter.